# Using classList method in square brackets

Tags: javascript

Is the putting a classList method inside square brackets considered as good practice? I mean, sometimes I prefer to do:

```
elem.classList[ifTrue ? 'add' : 'remove']('className');
```

as opposed to:

```
if (ifTrue) {
    elem.classList.add('className');
} else {
    elem.classList.remove('className');
}
```

Also, does using brackets have any impact on the performance/speed of code execution?

Comment: I don't know performance-wise, but the top notation is harder to read and less flexible.  And performance differences (if any) are probably going to be minute.

Comment: First part (good practice) is opinion-based (my vote: please don't write that, you're killing readability). Second part (performance) would (a) depend on the JS engine in use (b) probably be a negligible difference (c) might even be worse. Time it and see, but really please don't, on behalf of future maintainers of your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the putting a classList method inside square brackets considered as good practice?

There's nothing really wrong with it. It's shorter, more concise, no code duplication. As you say, you *sometimes* prefer it - if you know when to use and when not, then it's fine. The factors are:

- **readability**. Much opinion-based. I like it, others don't. Know your audience, I wouldn't suggest this for newbies.
- **maintainability**. When it's likely that other things need to be done depending on `ifTrue`, then I'd choose if-else. On the other hand, the repetion of `elem.classlist` and `'classname'` are not optimal either.
- **performance**. The second is more likely to be optimised (because static method names), that's true. But there hardly is measurable *impact* on your execution speed, as the most significant work is done in the DOM. You're not using this piece of code in a performance-critical section anyway. (Do you? Then benchmark).

---

There is a completely different and much better third way though: Using the [`toggle` method of classlists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). It does take a second parameter which does just what you want to do:

```
elem.classList.toggle('className', ifTrue);
```

It was just invented for this very common case! Admittedly, it's worse for readability as many developers don't know what `toggle` does.